# Ошибка при установке pyautogui: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно

Tags: python

**Вот ошибка**

> C:\Users\"имя пользователя">pip install pyautogui Collecting pyautogui Using cached 
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/f5/d7b39c588c2ef64e537
>   471e53e5750a426a1a78dcab9e65f502f4b022704/PyAutoGUI-0.9.42.tar.gz
>   Error [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно while executing command
>   python se tup.py egg_info Could not install packages due to an
>   EnvironmentError: [WinError 87]  Параметр задан неверно
>
> You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade
>   pip'  command.

**Помогите исправить ошибку**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у тебя устаревшая версия pip'a
Попробуй прописать в консоли ('python -m pip install --upgrade pip') (без кавычек)
Должно помочь

Comment: Не настолько устаревшая, чтобы это было проблемой